# How to compare dates with different formats?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the years/months passed since a particular date, but the two dates were first incompatible. I tried to map the second one to timestamp format.

```
today=pd.Timestamp("today").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
print("Todays date:",today)
```

But the `-`operation is not working.

```
df_grid=pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/b0219113/Documents/A_NCRT/Project Thena/Mapinfo/500 m/Sample output1 - Copy.csv',parse_dates=['SC SR Date'],dayfirst=True)

for i in range(len(df_grid)):
    df_grid["Time since plan"].iloc[i]=df_grid["SC SR Date"].iloc[i]-today
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your solution subtract `today` converting to strings `MM/DD/YYY`, so raise error.

If need remove times from `Timestamp` use [`Timestamp.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.normalize.html), for subtract values in columns remove loops for faster vectorized solution:

```
today = pd.Timestamp("today").normalize()
df_grid["Time since plan"] = df_grid["SC SR Date"] - today
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: @Adriaan - Sure, give me a sec. ;)

Comment: @KeyaParida - so it means in column `"SC SR Date"` is same datetime? 300 days before today?

Comment: Yes, i think issue is in the code loop. Can you have a look at it once?

Comment: @KeyaParida - my solution is necessary use instead your, so no loop.